# Fetch para consultas PDO

Tags: php, sql, mvc, pdo, fetch

El problema es el siguiente, tengo 2 tablas en donde necesito guardar datos, la primera se llama Usuario y la segunda la llamaremos Docente. El Usuario guarda:

Cod_Usuario, usuario, password, tipo y estado.

Necesito registrar el usuario, (Eso lo hace bien) luego de eso, inmediatamente hacer una consulta a esa tabla de la base de datos, con el usuario y password que recien ingrese.

AQUI VIENE EL PROBLEMA

De esa consulta que me devuelve todo un registro, necesito extraer solo el campo del Cod_Usuario, y ese Cod_Usuario, lo necesito para registrarlo como ForeignKey en la tabla Docente.

Antes lo hacia directamente con `mysqli_fetch_assoc();`
Pero ahora no estoy seguro, creo que el problema es ese, que no puedo extraer ese dato, y me salta un error.

Aquí les dejo mi código, si ven cual es el error me avisa se los agradecería enserio

```
$queryCodUsuario = $this->DB->connect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM Usuarios Where usuario = :user and password = :password');
$queryCodUsuario->execute(['user' => $datos['email'], 'password' => $md5Password]);
            
$row = $queryCodUsuario->fetch();
$newCodUser=$row['Cod_Usuario'];

//Insertamos todos los datos a la tabla Docente
$queryRegistrarUsuario = $this->DB->connect()->prepare('INSERT INTO plantel_docente_administrativo ("RDA", "Cod_Usuario", "nombre","apellidoPaterno",
"apellidoMaterno", "nro_Carnet", "fechaNacimiento", "sexo", "direccion", "celular") 
VALUES (:RDA, :newCodUser, :nombre, :apellidoPaterno, :apellidoMaterno,
:nro_Carnet, :fechaNacimiento, :sexo, :direccion, :celular )');

$queryRegistrarUsuario->execute(["RDA" => $datos['RDA'],
"newCodUser" => $newCodUser,
"nombre" => $datos['nombre'],
"apellidoPaterno" => $datos['apellidoPaterno'],
"apellidoMaterno" => $datos['apellidoMaterno'],
"nro_Carnet" => $datos['numCarnet'],
"fechaNacimiento" => $datos['fechaNacimiento'],
"sexo" => $datos['sexo'],
"direccion" => $datos['direccion'],
"celular" => $datos['celular']
]);
return true;
```

Comment: Ayudaría mucho indiques cual es el error obtenido

Comment: Muchas Gracias, ya solucione el problema. El Fetch() por si solo funciona. Al parecer mi problema era el tipo de comillas que usaba para hacer el INSERT.

Comment: Parafraseando a A.Cedano: *tu consulta es demasiado optimista* pues no maneja ningún control ante eventuales errores, te recomiendo [empieces por aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorinfo.php)

Comment: Las validaciones las hago primero en html (con los inputs y values) luego, con JS antes de enviarse al formulario vuelvo a verificar los datos de entrada(longitud, tipo de dato, duplicados, etc) , y finalmente en PHP hay una función que valida nuevamente que los datos antes de registrarse sigan un orden esperado. Una vez pasa todo eso recien entran a registrar en la base de datos. El problema era una validacion anterior, ingresaba un dato de 8 caracteres cuando solo se permitian 7.